# Map made with ggplot2 and sf packages, is not plotted properly with the specific projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

For one of the past weeks' `TidyTuesday` challenge, I am trying to make a map using `ggplot2` and `sf` packages with a different projection to try it out. I am very beginner to use a different projection to make a map, so my question might be a bit confusing. Yet, with the code and the output, I hope I will make myself clear.

So, here is the code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(showtextdb)
library(ggtext)

sf_use_s2(TRUE)

us_place_names <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-06-27/us_place_names.csv')
us_place_history <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-06-27/us_place_history.csv')

us_place_names_tidied <- us_place_names %>%
  drop_na(prim_long_dec, prim_lat_dec) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("prim_long_dec", "prim_lat_dec"), crs=4326) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -140, xmax = -68, ymin = 15, ymax = 50) %>%
  st_transform(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) 

usa <- maps::map("world", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE) %>% # a different way to load world countries' geo data into the working environment
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(ID %in% c("USA", "Canada")) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -140, xmax = -64, ymin = 10, ymax = 48) %>%
  st_transform(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) 


lakes <- maps::map("lakes", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -140, xmax = -55, ymin = 15, ymax = 40) %>%
  st_transform(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) 


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "#1D7874") +
  geom_sf(data = usa %>% filter(ID == "USA"), fill = "#231709", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = lakes , fill = "lightblue", color = "transparent") +
  geom_sf(data = us_place_names_tidied, size = 0.0000001, color = "#FF8551", alpha = 0.1) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100"))
```

and here is the map

[image]

So, as can be seen from the above code, I am trying to use a different projection and the resulting map's northern part has a weird linear appearance, while I expect something more elliptical due to the specific projection I set. Considering that the southern, western and eastern parts have more elliptical shapes, I could not figure out what the problem is and therefore I do appreciate your attention and help beforehand.

Comment: not sure what is wrong with st_crop but I think that's the reason for the wrong map visualization. So, when you crop us_place_names to make us_place_names_tidied, if you comment the st_crop and just filter latitude and longitude (before creating the SF using st_as_sf): filter(prim_lat_dec < 50, prim_lat_dec > 15, prim_long_dec < -68, prim_long_dec > -140) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("prim_long_dec", "prim_lat_dec"), crs=4326) ... then, it will be fixed. The interesting part about it is that st_crop won't make any issue when we use it for lakes...

Comment: did that really work out? Because I am receiving the same output still. Can you share the whole code if that's possible,  and also when I run the first two lines,  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "#1D7874"), it still throws out the same weird output so I think the problem is related to the coordinates of usa object not the us_place_names_tidied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because cropping by polygon in fact cuts the feature with straight lines, from one vertex to another, and don't create other vertex, which may help during transformation. Let's have a look on your example:

```r
usa <- maps::map("world", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE) |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  subset(ID %in% c("USA", "Canada")) |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  sf::st_crop(xmin = -140, xmax = -64, ymin = 10, ymax = 48)
  
usa |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = sf::st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) |>
  plot()
```

[image]

As said, cropping by polygon in fact generates straight line from one polygon vertex to another (modulo vertex in cropped feature). And please remember that latitude and longitude aren't X and Y coordinates, rather lambda an phi.

Let's create a polygon with 4 vertices (your's `xmin`, `xmax`...) and intersect the `usa` with this polygon:

```r
lon <- c(-140, -64)
lat <- c(10, 48)
  
poly = data.frame(lon, lat) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "EPSG:4326") |> 
  sf::st_bbox() |> 
  sf::st_as_sfc() |>
  sf::st_as_sf()
  
poly
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -140 ymin: 10 xmax: -64 ymax: 48
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                                x
#> 1 POLYGON ((-140 10, -64 10, ...

usb <- sf::st_intersection(usa, poly) |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = sf::st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) |>
  plot()
```

[image]

Result is the same.

But then, let's add "vertices" to our polygon by creating a grid:

```r
polc <- sf::st_make_grid(poly, n = c(20, 20), crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

plot(polc, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

And let's intersect `usa` with our grid, then transform it to desired projection. `group_by` and `summarise` from `{dplyr}` are used to union back grids together.

```r
usc <-  sf::st_intersection(usa, polc) |>
  dplyr::group_by(ID) |>
  dplyr::summarise()

usc |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = sf::st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100")) |>
  plot()
```

[image]

And the same with ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usc, fill = "#1D7874") +
  geom_sf(data = usc |> subset(ID == "USA"), fill = "#231709", color = "black") +
  # geom_sf(data = lakes , fill = "lightblue", color = "transparent") +
  # geom_sf(data = us_place_names_tidied, size = 0.0000001, color = "#FF8551", alpha = 0.1) +
  coord_sf(crs = sf::st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I do appreciate your detailed solution. Thanks for sparing time and helping out to find a solution.